# Understanding and overcoming AmbiguousRuleException in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a complicated workflow which I progressively extended. The last extension resulted in an `AmbiguousRuleException`. I tried to reproduce the critical structure of the workflow in the following example:

```python
NUMBERS = ["1", "2"]
LETTERS = ["a", "b", "c"]
WORDS = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
CHOICES = ["yes", "no"]


rule all:
    input:
        # (1)
        expand("results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.md5sum", word=WORDS, choice=CHOICES)
        #expand("results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.md5sum", word=WORDS + ["all"], choice=CHOICES)

rule make_things:
    output:
        "results/{letter}_{number}/{word}_{choice}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        echo "{wildcards.letter}_{wildcards.number}_{wildcards.word}_{wildcards.choice}" > {output}
        """

rule gather_things:
    input:
        expand("results/{letter}_{number}/{{word}}_{{choice}}.txt", letter=LETTERS, number=NUMBERS)
    output:
        "results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.txt"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output}
        """

# (2)
#rule join_all_words:
#    input:
#        expand("results/allthings/{word}_{{choice}}.txt", word=WORDS)
#    output:
#        "results/allthings/all_{choice}.txt"
#    shell:
#        """
#        cat {input} > {output}
#        """
# (3)
#def source_data(wildcards):
#    if wildcards.word == "all":
#        return rules.join_all_words.output
#    else:
#        return rules.gather_things.output

rule compute_md5:
    input:
        # (4)
        rules.gather_things.output,
        #source_data
    output:
        "results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.md5sum"
    shell:
        """
        md5sum {input} > {output}
        """
```

The above state is functional. Switching `(1)` and `(4)` and uncommenting `(2)` and `(3)` correspond to the extension I'm trying to make, and results in the following failure:

```
AmbiguousRuleException:
Rules gather_things and join_all_words are ambiguous for the file results/allthings/all_yes.txt.
Expected input files:
    gather_things: results/a_1/all_yes.txt results/a_2/all_yes.txt results/b_1/all_yes.txt results/b_2/all_yes.txt results/c_1/all_yes.txt results/c_2/all_yes.txt
    join_all_words: results/allthings/foo_yes.txt results/allthings/bar_yes.txt results/allthings/baz_yes.txt
```

It seems that snakemake thinks that `results/allthings/all_yes.txt` can be generated by `gather_things`.

**Why?**

**How can I avoid that?**

---

Note: The goal of modifications `(3)` and `(4)` is to have the `compute_md5` work on both the direct output of `gather_things` (for `foo`, `bar` and `baz`) and the joined output of the three (`all`), keeping input defined in terms of other rule's output as much as possible (which makes changes easier than when file names are explicitly used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2017-07-28 Post edited for brevity**

Initially I thought it was just ambiguity. The first 3 points relate to resolving ambiguity. Afterwards, I explain how to generalize 'compute_md5' to achieve desired behaviour.

## Controlling ambiguity

1) Control flowing the ambiguity:

**ruleorder**
http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=ruleorder#handling-ambiguous-rules

I suggest avoiding this in the following situation. In the grand hopes of modularity, by using "ruleorder" you are essentially coupling two rules together. The "ruleorder" functionality can only be used if both rules are present within the Snakefile's scope. This can be a problem with modularization if the rules are not always provided together. If they rules are always provided together, I would argue they are already coupled, and doing this doesn't make the situation worse, in fact, in increases cohesion. Use "ruleorder" when using 'constraints' isn't enough, as sometimes where will be unavoidable ambiguity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

**conditional 'includes'** 
https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/tree/master/modules/bamGen

Rule order is in the "_INCLUDE"
Outputs for sam2BAM and bamALIGN_bwa are very similar, mainly becuase sam2BAM is so generic.

Because bamALIGN_bwa and bamALIGN_star are technically switchable, and I didn't want users swapping around ruleorder just to switch between them, I have a boolean which I store in my YAML file, to act as a hard filter to literally prevent Snakemake from even seeing the rule. This works great in situations where you can ONLY pick one or the other (In this case, the two aligners have their own reference genomes. I force the user to set the reference genome at the begging of my pipeline so users could NEVER actually run both. I have not implemented functionality to detect which reference genome is being used such that the corresponding aligner is then chosen. This would be some over-head python code, great idea, but not currently implemented).

2) Asking Snakemake to ignore the ambiguity.

With an over-ride. It exists, but I think "--allow-ambiguity" should be avoided whenever possible.

http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=--allow-ambiguity#handling-ambiguous-rules

3) Elegantly ~ Preventing the ambiguity.

http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=wildcard_constraints#wildcards

```
rule gather_things:
     input:
         expand("results/{letter}_{number}/{{word}}_{{choice}}.txt", letter=LETTERS, number=NUMBERS)
     output:
         "results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.txt"
      wildcard_constraints:
         word='[^(all)][0-9a-zA-Z]*'
...
```

This rule needs a wildcard_constraint, to prevent it from competing with the "join_all_words" rule. This is done easily by preventing the wildcard "word" here, from being the string 'all'. This makes "gather_things" and "join_all_words" differentiable.

## compute_md5 generalizability

As for getting "compute_md5" to accept input from both "gather_things" and "join_all_words", this requires making it more generalized, nothing to do with ambiguity. The next thing you need to do is adjust the "join_all_words" rule, such that it is not dependent on ANY given rule's input.

https://github.com/tboyarski/BCCRC-Snakemake/blob/master/help/download.svg

I just want to also thank you for providing a TOP-NOTCH example to work from. Brilliant!

```
 NUMBERS = ["1", "2"]
 LETTERS = ["a", "b", "c"]
 WORDS = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
 CHOICES = ["yes", "no"]


 rule all:
     input:
         expand("results/allthings/all_{choice}.md5sum", choice=CHOICES),
         expand("results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.md5sum", word=WORDS, choice=CHOICES)

 rule make_things:
     output:
         "results/{letter}_{number}/{word}_{choice}.txt"
     shell:
         """
         echo "{wildcards.letter}_{wildcards.number}_{wildcards.word}_{wildcards.choice}" > {output}
         """

 rule gather_things:
     input:
         expand("results/{letter}_{number}/{{word}}_{{choice}}.txt", letter=LETTERS, number=NUMBERS)
     output:
         "results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.txt"
     wildcard_constraints:
         word='[^(all)][0-9a-zA-Z]*'
     shell:
         """
         cat {input} > {output}
         """

 rule join_all_words:
     input:
         expand("results/allthings/{word}_{{choice}}.txt", word=WORDS)
     output:
         "results/allthings/all_{choice}.txt"
     shell:
         """
         cat {input} > {output}
         """

 rule compute_md5:
     input:
         "{pathCMD5}/{sample}.txt"
     output:
         "{pathCMD5}/{sample}.md5sum"
         #"results/allthings/{word}_{choice}.md5sum"
     shell:
         """
         md5sum {input} > {output}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested the `ruleorder` solution, and I initially used the wrong order. "all" was used in `make_things` and no conspicuous crash ensued. So one has to be careful with this way of doing.

What do you mean by "allow the ambiguity with an over-ride"?

I didn't know that wildcard constraints could be used inside a rule. I think that's the information that was missing for me to find a good solution. Constraining `word = "|".join(WORDS)` in `make_things` or in `gather_things` both work. I'm wondering what is the cleaner choice.

Comment: I added a note in my question, about the `source_data` input function.

Comment: Regarding the choice between star and bwa (or any choice between tools), I think the "right thing" is to use the name of the aligner in the path of the files generated from the alignment step and downstream. This can be a wildcard (if you want to run both) or just a variable read from the configuration file.

Comment: I confirm that the graph you show corresponds to the wanted behaviour. Just using the wildcards trick actually works, no need to change anything else.